# STOP Spring Batch Job with in-memory database Hsql

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a scenario where I am using in-memory database for Spring batch job.
with configuration.

```
batch.jdbc.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:xdb
batch.jdbc.user=
batch.jdbc.password=
```

It's running fine if I only executes a single job but problem comes when I want to stop this job via CommandLineJobRunner it's again creating the database(I have overridden the sql-script to create and drop schema) and it's not getting the executionID and giving NPE.

Please suggest what can I do to run this job.

Comment: Use a real database... The in memory database is created for each application you start, each has its own. Use a file based database with HSQL or use a real database.

Comment: you could wrap the start/stop functions with something that takes user input to stop the (running) job, like this http://www.coderanch.com/t/468006/java/java/program-running-user-terminates